# Symfony / Doctrine - Display products from database by category children and parent

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I've created *self-referenced* **category** entity, **product** entity with *many-to-many* relationship to **category** entity.

Example categories list:

```
MacBooks
-MacBook Air
--MacBook Air 11
--MacBook Air 13
-MacBook Pro
--MacBook Pro 13
```

I'm getting products based on selected category.

```
public function getByCategory($category)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
    $qb->leftJoin('p.categories', 'c');
    $qb->where('c.url = :category');
    $qb->setParameter('category', $category);

    return $qb->getQuery()->useQueryCache(true);
}
```

For example product is inside a category **MacBook Air 13**.

So my code works only if I select the category **MacBook Air 13**.

But how to show products in parent category? 
For example in category **MacBook Air** I want to display products from categories MacBook Air 11 **and** MacBook Air 13, etc...

Same in category **MacBooks** display everything from MacBook Air, MacBook Air 11, MacBook Air 13, etc...?

Question simplification:
How to get all products from all children.

MacBook -> MacBook Air -> MacBook Air 11, MacBook Air 13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try one thing. Get all children and parents of given category first, then use `where...in` in your query builder. We can do it with recursive calls.

YourController.php:

```
public function someAction(int $id)
{

// ...

    $category = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:Category')->find($id);

    $categories = $this->getAllCategories($category);
// OR
//  $categories = $this->getAllChildren($category);

    $products = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:Product')->getByCategories($categories);

// ...

}

private function getAllCategories(Category $category)
{       
    return array_merge(
        $this->getAllChildren($category), 
        $this->getAllParents($category)
    );
}

private function getAllChildren(Category $category) 
{
    static $categories = array();
    $categories[] = $category->getId();

    if(!$category->getChildren()->isEmpty()) 
    {
        foreach($category->getChildren() as $child) 
        {
            $this->getAllChildren($child);
        }
    }

    return $categories;
}

private function getAllParents(Category $category) 
{
    static $categories = array();

    if($category->getParent()) 
    {
        $categories[] = $category->getParent()->getId();
        $this->getAllParents($category->getParent());
    }

    return $categories;
}
```

ProductRepository.php:

```
// ...

public function getByCategories(array $categories)
{
    $qb = $this ->createQueryBuilder('p')
                ->leftJoin('p.categories', 'c');
    $qb->where($qb->expr()->in('c.id', $categories));

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}

// ...
```

So we can get all products from category and all its children and parents or just from category and all its children.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow, this solution is so much better than mine. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help you. I'm sure you know what you can move this logic from controller to some service. It would be a better practice.